# Jenkins Error 503 on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-503

I have created an AWS Ec2 instance using the following documentation:

https://d0.awsstatic.com/Projects/P5505030/aws-project_Jenkins-build-server.pdf

However, when I get to the stage where I connect from my web browser to Jenkins using http://:8080 I get HTTP Error: 503.

I originally taught it was down to my network settings/security group settings on my AWS EC2 instance but I have installed Apache and I can access the Apache test page from port 80. I have allowed traffic from HTTP, SSH and TCP and set the appropriate ports as per the guide.

I have tried curl http://localhost:8080 on the putty instance connected to my EC2 instance and I get the same error. Also, I have checked the /var/lib/jenkins folder and it is empty.

Any help or direction in the right path would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: If `/var/lib/jenkins` is empty, either you didn't install Jenkins or you installed it in a non-default directory. To find out where you installed it, you might try `find / | grep jenkins`. Also, if you are using curl from a different instance than the one that you believe to have installed Jenkins on, you will want to do `curl http://IP-OF-JENKINS-INSTANCE:8080` instead of `curl http://localhost:8080` as the Jenkins instance will not respond to a call to localhost on a different instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have used "sudo yum install jenkins -y" also I used curl on the instance I have installed Jenkins on.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into this problem in the future, the documentation installs the latest version of Jenkins.

I installed an older, stable Jenkins version and this worked perfectly using the "sudo yum install jenkins-2.47-1.1"

Comment: thank you, spent 4 hours trying to figure 503 error before running into you answer. once install 2.47-1.1 error went away

Comment: Hey @mike.tihonchik . Glad it helped. It's strange , It works perfectly on a Windows EC2 instance with the latest version of Jenkins. It's not really ideal having to resort to an older version. I was running short on time as it was for college work but would have been interested to see which versions work and which versions don't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by installing Java 8.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43609